# Selenium Webdriver Java Element Cannot be scrolled into view

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon everyone, this issue has been causing me to consider punching my laptop. In the code below I am simply hovering over a drop down menu and selecting a link from it. Now the issue is randomly I receive "Element cannot be scrolled into view" for the link I am selecting. This happens about 50% of the time, what visually happens is it hovers over the drop down menu then the screen jumps down cutting off where the menu would be and throws the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
WebDriverWait waitForDropDown = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    waitForDropDown.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Create Test Case")));
    Action builder;
    Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement objectOnScreen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Lab"));
    hover.moveToElement(objectOnScreen);
    builder = hover.build();
    builder.perform();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Create Test Case")).click();
```

Comment: So I think I have fixed this finally. I added another wait after the hover and it has not reproduced since.

Comment: scratch that still fails

Comment: So just read that this is a known issue and has been for a couple years, wish they would fix this already.

Answer (score 0):

How are the links generated?  Could the link text be changing?

I would suggest trying this:

```
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait waitForDropDown = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement objectOnScreen = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test Lab")); //Use a CSS locator, not link text
WebElement objectToClick = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Create Test Case")); //Use a CSS locator, not link text

hover.moveToElement(objectOnScreen).perform();
waitForDropDown.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(objectToClick));  
hover.moveToElement(objectToClick).click();
```

Generally link text is a very brittle locator that shouldn't be used.  CSS locaters are a much better option.